# SQL Server: Returning UniqueIdentifier, Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting this error when trying to return a unique identifier from a stored procedure - thoughts?

> Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int

Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST
AS
    RETURN NEWID()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stored procedures can only 'return' an `INT` (it's meant to be used as a status code). If you want to get other data out of a stored procedure, you should `SELECT` it. Accessing that data from the code making the call may be a little different, but that's how you have to do it.

For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test
AS
    SELECT NEWID()
```

Comment: Alternatively, return one or more values with out parameters, The main point is that a stored procedure is not a scalar function.

Comment: @DanGuzman, yes, `OUT` parameters work too, but are usually more complicated to work with (mostly because they're not used as often as `SELECT` is).

Answer (score 1):

Procedures in SQL Server do not return values . . . well, there is an implicit integer status, but that is not what you want.

Perhaps you intend:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST (
    @out_id uniqueidentifier output
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @out_id = NEWID();
END;
```

Or, perhaps you want to define a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TEST
RETURNS uniqueidentifier
BEGIN
    RETURN NEWID();
END;
```

However, I don't believe you can really do this, because `newid()` is considered to have side effects -- and that is not allowed in a SQL Server function.